# How to get a token from this construction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My action should return the generated token. Using the comparePassword model method, I check the passwords and, if successful, generate a token. But I can not get the generated token. I only get user data from the database.

```js
    
    signIn: (data) => {
        const response = user.Instance.findOne({
            username: data.username
        }, (err, user) => {
            if (!user) {
                return {success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'};
            } else {
                // check if password matches
                user.comparePassword(data.password, (err, result) => {
                    if (result && !err) {
                        // if user is found and password is right create a token
                        var token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), 'nodeauthsecret', {
                            expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
                        });
                        
                        // return the information including token as JSON
                        return {success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token};
                    } else {
                        return {success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'};
                    }
                });
            }
        });
                
        return response;
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign method is async and you're not explicitly waiting for its execution to finish.

Therefore, the response will be immediately returned after `findOne` finishes it's execution which will happen regardless of the outputs of `user.comparePassword`.

You can use a Promise for this - something like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    user.Instance.findOne({
        username: data.username
    }, (err, user) => {
        if (!user) {
            reject({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
        } else {
            // check if password matches
            user.comparePassword(data.password, (err, result) => {
                if (result && !err) {
                    // if user is found and password is right create a token
                    jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), 'nodeauthsecret', {
                        expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
                    }, (err, token) => {
                        if (err) reject(err);
                        resolve({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
                    });
                }
                reject({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
            });
        }
    });
})
```

**Edit**: The function will reject invalid authorisation attempts. You have to catch those and return the response properly. For example:

```
routes.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    return user.signIn(req.body)
        .then(data => res.send(data))
        .catch(err => res.status(401).send(err))
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work for me. I have already tried this method, but I am getting these errors.

Comment: (node:11896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
(node:11896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11896) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Here is my controller where I call this action:
routes.post('/signin', async (req, res) =>  {
  const userSignIn = await user.signIn(req.body);
  res.send(userSignIn);
 });

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are getting user data indicates that comparePassword() is working. What is the exact response that you are getting?
Just a security note: I would recommend not sending the user.toJSON() in JWT token since that contains the password too.

Comment: Also JWT.sign() is synchronous if you do not provide a callback, so that part of your code seems correct.

Comment: I am generating a token. But I can not add the token to the variable response or any other.

Comment: What is  the result of console.log(response)?